# Cross-browser upload big files over HTTP (partly)?

Tags: http, file-upload

I need to upload big files over http without affecting IIS timeout (using multiple independent requests).
Should I use any plug-ins or it is possible with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server side language to process the request, since you mentioned you are using IIS I will assume .Net

What you need is Asynchronous File Upload - somthing like this http://swfupload.org/node/47